# pypy gives error when trying to read global variable

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to do a compiler to a simple language. I am using pypy, but
for some reason, i can't access a global variable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
  File "c.py", line 80, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(main(sys.stdin) + '\n')
  File "c.py", line 75, in main
    process()
  File "c.py", line 58, in process
    l(n)
  File "c.py", line 9, in l
    ot += [tline[0], '('] + tline[1:-1] + [') {']
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ot' referenced before assignment
```

The problem here is that `ot` is a global variable.
I already have put `global ot` before.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code, not just the error. Ideally, post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: add `global ot` before `+=` operation.